# backbone.paginator - update per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, pagination

I'm using `backbone.paginator` in my project.  I have a dropdown that allows users to select the results per page.  Now all I have to do is figure out how to make it work :-)

So far if I do something like this:

```
this.collection.goTo(page, {
    data: {per_page: newResultsPerPage}
});
```

where `newResultsPerPage` is the number of results the user has selected from the dropdown.  The correct number of results come back from the server, but `backbone.paginator` doesn't correctly update the number of pages.  Is there a method I can call that will update / reset the `backbone.paginator` plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a `howManyPer` method that I missed in the documentation.  I'll leave this question up for anyone else searching for a similar issue in the future.